# Прорисовка границы ячейки таблицы

Tags: c#, winforms

Работаю с WinForms. В DataGrid ячейки - DataGridViewImageCell. Вокруг каждой ячейки рисуется рамка (при Paint):

```
using (Brush border_brush = new SolidBrush(<COLOR>))
{
    using (Pen border_pen = new Pen(border_brush, <WIDTH>))
    {
        var rect = <DATAGRID>.GetCellDisplayRectangle(<Y>, <Y>, true);
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(border_pen, rect);
    }
}
```

После прокрутки таблицы, разумеется это все слетает, т.к. прорисовка зависит от полученных координат ячейки. Единственных путем кажется изменение каждого рисунка ячейки (т.е. добавление на существующий рисунок нужной рамки). Как можно еще решить эту проблему?

Comment: Делайте это в событии [CellPainting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellpainting?view=net-5.0)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, при таком методе границы моментально пропадают. Если же здесь использовать ```Refresh()```, то ячейки, конечно, постоянно мигают

Comment: + к этому пропадает изображение в ячейке

Comment: Покажите код, как вы делаете. / Используйте свойства и методы параметра `DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e`. Не используйте члены самого датагрида, наподобие `GetCellDisplayRectangle`.

Answer (score 0):

Благодарность [Alexander Petrov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/184217/alexander-petrov)!

```
private void DGV_functions_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
    using (Brush border_brush = new SolidBrush(<COLOR>))
    {
        using (Pen border_pen = new Pen(border_brush, <WIDTH>))
        {
            Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(
                e.CellBounds.X,
                e.CellBounds.Y, 
                e.CellBounds.Width,
                e.CellBounds.Height
            );

            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(border_pen, rect);
        }
    }

    e.Handled = true;            
}
```

Comment: Можно просто использовать `e.CellBounds`. Таким образом, `Rectangle rect` не нужен.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, хотелось бы узнать, почему здесь "мешают" вызовы методов самого датагрида?

Comment: Либо мы сами полностью рисуем всё в `CellPainting`, либо оставляем как есть (грид сам себя рисует). | События происходят в разном порядке. Какие-то свойства уже поменялись, а какие-то ещё нет (поменяются в следующем по порядку событии) - поэтому их нельзя использовать.